# color every nth row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I understand (in a limited way) how to use conditional formatting in Excel 2010.
I have a calendar type of display across many columns, in one row, like this:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
I want to color 2 days green, 2 days red, 2 days orange, 2 days blue, then repeat.
I could do it manually, but I'd like to make a calendar that displays more than just this year. Leap years change the format, the 1st doesn't always come on Monday, etc.
Is there a way to do this with conditional formatting so that when the calendar updates, the colors do as well?

Each day/date occupies a single cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point try using this as a a formula for conditional formatting. This will effect every other row.

```
=MOD(ROW(), 2)=1
```

Comment: I'd say `=OR(MOD(ROW(),8)=1,MOD(ROW(),8)=2)` to get two rows coloured the same, then use =3 & 4,  5 & 6, 7 & 0,

Comment: Yes it will. My dates run horizontal, across rows. so =MOD(column()...) would be appropriate. But it still leaves the conundrum of coloring 2,2,2,2 then repeating with that format.

Comment: Then Change `Row()` to `Column()`

Comment: Right now, this works best. I just have to start the next year on a column() that matches up with the end of the last year to get it to carry over. The good thing is, this is not for display, just for formatting. The appropriate cells will be copied (with format) to a display sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to use the conditional formatting and not vba to do this. I have a calendar in which I highlight weekends, but you could extrapolate it to your case.
The formula you're searching for is the so called `WEEKDAY` How the week starts is self explainatory if you try it in a cell.
Let's say your dates are in the range A1:A30. The condition which will trigger the formatting would be 
 `=OR(WEEKDAY(A$1;2)=1;WEEKDAY(A$1;2)=2)` for Monday and Tuesday 
 `=OR(WEEKDAY(A$1;2)=3;WEEKDAY(A$1;2)=4))` for Wednesday and Thursday 
and so on.
Excel will handle leap years for you, so don't worry about that. 
And to fill the days, just type the first one in A1 and in A2 `=A1+1`and expand it all along.

Comment: VBA would be great. I run into a problem at the end of the year. When Dec 31 has red and is the first red cell, Jan 1 should be red also to continue the pattern. Since this runs on a six day cycle, weekdays won't work. this week will be Sun & Mon red, Tue & wed orange, Thu & Fri green, Sat & Sun blue, Mon & Tue red, Wed & Thu orange, etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the six day cycle as you mention all weekdays and the color change occurs every 8. Anyway, to carry the day color to the next sheet maybe you could use the method @Darrenb suggested (`MOD`), but applying it to the date itself instead of applying it to the column.